Meaning of "полюбиться"
I'm unsure about the meaning of the fourth verse:

А умею научить,
Чтоб нежданное случилось,
Как навеки приручить
Ту, что мельком полюбилась.

which is an excerpt from Нет, царевич, я не та… by Anna Akhmatova.
It was translated into Italian as "colei che si è innamorata in un baleno" (No, tesoruccio, io non sono quella...), which means "the one who fell in love in a flash", and into English as "Her, whose love is so rapid" (No, my prince, I am not the one...).
But on the грамота site, we have the following definition:

ПОЛЮБИТЬСЯ, -люблюсь, -любишься; св. кому. 1. Разг. Сильно понравиться кому-л., прийтись по вкусу. Песня полюбилась. Чем-то полюбился начальству. [] безл. Ушёл со службы, не полюбилось. Ей полюбилось бродить по спящим улицам. 2. кому с кем. Нар.-разг. Вызвать сердечную привязанность, влечение, любовь. П. друг другу. Ты мне сразу полюбился. 3. безл. Нар.-разг. Придётся, захочется полюбить; возникнет любовь. Придёт время - полюбится. Полюби другого, коль полюбится.

According to this definition (and especially to the second item), I would translate in the opposite way: "the one with whom you fell in love in a flash". Which is the correct interpretation?

As for the verb, yours is the right interpretation: та, которая полюбилась means "the one who you fell in love with".
Note that ты мне полюбилась conveys a slightly less strong feeling than я влюбился в тебя, albeit still a romantic one.
That said, мельком is neither in un baleno nor "in a flash". It means "briefly, in passing", meaning that the feeling was not permanent.
I would have used di cui ti sei innamorato di sfuggita (or maybe even a cui hai voluto bene) for the Italian version, and "for whom you've briefly had feelings" for the English one.
